# Freezes MacBook pro

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro

i have a mid 2010 macbook pro 4gb ram and nvidia card 13.3" . Sadly enough a few months after I bought it it started freezing . The screen is just static and unreaponsive. prior to that i installed and then uninstalled win7 via bootcamp. I recall having a crash during a reset and my macbook lost 250gb of it's capacity.
I then also started to hear weird clicks or tweets every few minutes.

4.5 years passed since theb and ive been suffering hard from random freezes that left me with no other choice but keeping hard rebooting it.

A few days ago i formatted it and reinstalled yosemite os after 7 tries (mac froze during installs) after completing a full install it worked finw for an hour or two but then it happend again.

Desperatly trying to figure if it's my ram my hdd or maybe graphic hardware problem.

Any assistance is welcome.

Comment: Ok. This is not disk fault for sure. Just got myself a crucial 120gb ssd and it froze during the first install. Managed to completley install it only at the 3rd time. So whats up next, ram?

Answer (score 1):

> I recall having a crash during a reset and my macbook lost 250gb of it's capacity. I then also started to hear weird clicks or tweets every few minutes.

Everything you've mentioned tells me your hard drive is faulty, that's what's clicking and tweeting, and why you're experiencing freezes and lockups.

Replace the drive with a new one.

Comment: Ok. This is not disk fault for sure. Just got myself a crucial 120gb ssd and it froze during the first install. Managed to completley install it only at the 3rd time. So whats up next, ram?

Answer (score 0):

If your hard disk drive supports [Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology (SMART)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.), you can use the `diskutil` command to query the SMART status. E.g.:

```
$ diskutil info disk0 | grep SMART
   SMART Status:             Failing
```

You can also check the [SMART status using the Disk Utility program](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2011/07/12#smart-status) found in Applications/Utilities. You will see S.M.A.R.T. status displayed near the bottom of the window when you select the drive.

You can use [Memtest OS X](http://www.memtestosx.org/) to test the system's memory, but as TECHIE007 noted, clicking sounds indicate a hard drive problem rather than a memory or video problem.